# How to change the name and folder of robot logs/report file?

Tags: python, eclipse, report, robotframework

I am new to robot framework.

I am using Robot framework-Python-Red editor plugin-eclipse to run my automation script.
Got the result as;

```
Output:  C:\Users\eclipse-workspace\MyProject\output.xml
Log:     C:\Users\eclipse-workspace\MyProject\log.html
Report:  C:\Users\eclipse-workspace\MyProject\report.html
```

I need 2 changes in the reports:

- All three files I need with name including timestamp. E.g.,
  **11062020_04.30_log.html**
- All three files should be in defined folder

I tried running it using command line like

```
robot -t login.robot
```

but it is not running giving an error of required argument. I was checking to change the folder by using

```
robot -d C:\myfolder
```

It looks it is working with only RED editor and not with the eclipse.
Please guide step by step.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Welcome.

**Output dir**

To change an output dir, you need to use `--outputdir` command line option, e.g. `--outputdir Results/` to save outputs into `Results` directory. Beware that it matters where you run the command from, so if your tests are in `<project_dir>/Tests` and you execute your tests like so:

```
$ cd Tests/
$ robot ...
```

then the outputdir option should be `--outputdir ../Results`.

**Timestamped filenames**

Robot has another command line option `--timestampoutput` for that.

**How to put it together?**

It's a bit annoying when you have to always type these options on the command line. And even if you run your tests in a pipeline, it's a little less error prone to set your command line options separately, not directly in the command. For that, you can create e.g. `arguments.txt` file in your project dir and include command line options in it, one per line like so:

```
--variable language:cz
--outputdir ../Results
--timestampoutput
--console verbose
--consolemarkers on
--loglevel TRACE:INFO
--tagdoc *:See *README.md*
--tagstatcombine smokeANDregression
```

then you can execute your tests with only `$ robot ..\arguments.txt` which is much shorter.

You can read more about creating outputs in the official dcumentation [here](https://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#created-outputs).

Comment: Thanks! That is working fine for me. Well another query to it. I have log in my defined directory. I sent the log/ report in mail attachment and it is opening fine at client but screenshots are not displaying there. How to keep screenshots in attached report.